# JFrame hided after closing his child

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I googled this problem a lot but can't find any answers. I have legacy system with three JFrame objects. They were created in one chain: first JFrame is parent for second one, second is parent for third.

The problem is after I close third window, the first window receive focus and the second one is going behind the first. And its wrong. I expect that after closing third JFrame focus will go to the second window. What could be the problem and how to fix this wrong behaviour?

Code looks something like this:

```
Frame first = new JFrame(null, "first");
JDialog second = new JDialog(first, "second"); 
JFrame third = new JFrame(second, "third");

third.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  // request focus in second window when focus lost in third
});
```

Comment: some code would help a lot:-)

Comment: Can you put a `WindowsListener` on closing `jframe2.requestFocusInWindow()` ?

Comment: the second window is instance of JDialod class. And it doesn't receive events in WindowListener. Even after dialog.requestFocus() or dialog.requestFocusInWindow().

Answer (score -1):

Using several JFrame objects in one application is a bad practice. See the following answer, that could help to change your implementation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/2239537

Comment: It's very difficult to change implementation if project was started in 1996. The project is really very big.

Comment: Then, please, provide some code, so that people could help you.